# Repeating Decimal

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

the repeating decimal $0.95863$ is repeated every $5$ numbers, what is the $44th$ digit?

My attempt is:

The remainder of dividing $44$ on $5$ is $4$ , so the $44th$ digit will be the fourth digit in $0.95863$ which is $5$

Comment: Are we starting with 0 or 1, from left to right or right to left?

Comment: My bad, what I meant is that the firth digit is the 0 remainder, thesecond the 1 remainder and so on, so 4 remainder is the fifth one, so 3

Comment: use modular arithmetic, calling the first 9 place 'zero'  so the one you want will then be place 43.  43 is congruent to 3 modulo 5, '3' is then the 4th decimal - which is 6

Answer (score -2):

> My attempt is:
>
> The remainder of dividing  on  is  , so the  digit will be the fourth
> digit in  0.95863 which is 5

You count from first so the 1st number is 9 and 2nd number is 5. So 4th number should be 6. Apart from that, your attempt is correct.